# Replaces the text in the given file - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am new to FAKE and trying to implement something in FAKE as described below :
I have a file having more than 100 lines, I want to change few lines in the code , let say I want to change  2nd line i.e. `IFR.SIIC._0.12` to 
`IFR.SIIC._0.45`

How will I do this . 
Will I do this using  ReplaceInFile  or  RegexReplaceInFileWithEncoding   ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many functions that could help you: which one you'll pick will depend on how you'd prefer to write your code. For example, `ReplaceInFile` wants you to supply it with a *function*, while `RegexReplaceInFileWithEncoding` wants you to give it a *regular expression* (in string form, not as a `Regex` object). Depending on what text you want to replace, one might be easier than the other. For example, you could use `ReplaceInFile` like so:

```
Target "ChangeText" (fun _ ->
    "D:\Files\new\oneFile.txt"  // Note *no* !! operator to change a single file
    |> ReplaceInFile (fun input ->
        match input with
        | "IFR.SIIC._0.12" -> "IFR.SIIC._0.45"
        | "another string" -> "its replacement"
        | s -> s // Anything else gets returned unchanged
    )
)
```

That would be useful if, for example, you have a set of *specific* strings that you want to match, in just a *single* file. However, there's a simpler function called `ReplaceInFiles` (note the plural) which allows you to replace text in *multiple* files at once. Also, instead of taking a *function* as its parameter, `ReplaceInFiles` takes a *sequence* of `(old,new)` pairs. This is often easier to write:

```
let stringsToReplace = [
    ("IFR.SIIC._0.12", "IFR.SIIC._0.45") ;
    ("another string", "its replacement")
]
Target "ChangeText" (fun _ ->
    !! "D:\Files\new\*.txt"
    |> ReplaceInFiles stringsToReplace
)
```

If you want to specify your search and replacement strings in the form a regular expression, then you'd want `RegexReplaceInFileWithEncoding` or `RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding` (note the plural: the former takes a single file while the latter takes multiple files). I'll just show you an example of the multiple-files version:

```
Target "ChangeText" (fun _ ->
    !! "D:\Files\new\*.txt"
    |> RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding @"(?<part1>\w+)\.(?<part2>\w+)\._0\.12"
                                       @"${part1}.${part2}._0.45"
                                       System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
)
```

That would allow you to change `IFR.SIIC._0.12` to `IFR.SIIC._0.45` and `ABC.WXYZ._0.12` to `ABC.WXYZ._0.45`.

Which one of these you'll want to use all depends on how many files you have, and how many different replacement strings you need (and how hard it would be to write them a regex).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome answer :)

Comment: hi rmunn : I want to replace string from a variable having string .
or like this :    
@"admintool: RBI.ICISApi.AdminTool_"+version_no    
I am getting an error "Unexpected quote symbol in binding"

Comment: @KMittal - That's probably a syntax error of some kind in your F# code, so I won't be able to answer your question without seeing the whole function. Open a new question and ask that again, and make sure to include a code sample. Show the entire function that has the error, and don't forget to indent it properly with the `{}` button.

Comment: @KMittal - On Stack Overflow, you shouldn't be using the comments section to ask new questions, because very few people will see your question that way. If you have a new question, just *ask a new question*, then more people will see it.

Comment: @KMittal - BTW, usually when you get the error "Unexpected (something) in binding" in F#, it means your indentation is messed up. So when you ask your new question, make *sure* to copy your function exactly as it appears in your code, then use the `{}` button to indent it by 4 spaces in the Stack Overflow editor. Because messed-up indentation is one of the most common mistakes an F# newbie makes, so we need to see *exactly* how your code is indented so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: @KMittal - See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/ for good guidelines on how to indent your F# code properly.

Comment: ReplaceInFile and ReplaceInFiles are both Visual Studio commands, yes?